# No ResultSet when using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 transactions in stored procs?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

So we have an app that calls into many stored procs in SQL Server 2008 R2. Most the stored procs are simple CRUD type ones (ie don't need to use transactions) and return some nice ResultSet objects into the Java code.

However we have one or two more complex ones that use transactions within the stored proc. These ones don't seem to return ResultSets when selecting information at the end of the transaction?

For example on stored proc goes something like the following;

```
ParentStoredProc;
    call generationStoredProc to generate a unique code
    begin transaction
        call childProc1 using generated code to insert some data
        call childProc2 using generated code to insert some data
    commit transaction
    select something from recently inserted data using generated code
```

Seems sensible? Generates a key value, inserts data into two different tables atomically using a transaction, select some of that data back and return it as a result for the parent stored proc. It in fact works great when called from within SQL Server Management Studio, the results are displayed just like any other select that didn't involve a transaction beforehand.

The issue is that when the Java code tries to call that using prepared statements and the execute method (which captures ResultSets just fine for all the other stored procs) there is no ResultSet coming back?

Its as tho the parentStoredProc is returning to the Java code as soon as it sees the transaction begins.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to get the results from the final select, which get returned just fine in the management studio, to return to the java app callableStatement.execute() ?